# Quote Trigger for Approved Quotes Only

Tags: trigger, approval-process, quote

Looking to add a trigger to prevent an "Approved" Quote from being deleted but at other stages you can delete the quote.    The other stages are "Not Submitted", "Pending", "Rejected", and "Recalled".   Field name is Approval Stage.  Any suggestions much appreciated?

I tried this trigger below but does not work but an error message is displayed at any stage and prevents deleting of the record.  Hoping for just when Approval Stage = Approved

What I have so far.

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" action="{!IF(Quote.Approval_Stage__c == 'Approved', NULL, URLFOR($Action.Quote.Delete, $CurrentPage.parameters.id, [retURL='/home/home.jsp'], TRUE))}">
    <apex:pageMessage title="Unauthorized" summary="The Quote is an {!Quote.Approval_Stage__c } state and hence cannot be deleted!" severity="ERROR" strength="3">
    </apex:pageMessage>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I presume this VF page is an override of the standard Delete button for Quote?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following trigger. Using a `Custom Label` to contain error text makes it configurable, so you can change it without additional deployments.

**Class**

```
public with sharing class QuoteServices
{
    public static void validateNotApproved(List<Quote> records)
    {
        for (Quote record : trigger.new)
        {
            if (record.Approval_Stage__c == 'Approved')
                record.addError('Replace this text with a Custom Label');
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger Quote on Quote (before delete)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isDelete)
        {
            validateNotApproved(trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apex Class has an error  from line 8, column 33 at the word Label

Comment: Missed an `=` character in the comparison.

Comment: = sign goes before ?

Comment: It's in the updated code.

Comment: not working - don't see the updated code

Comment: updated code with 2 = signs , same error message.

Comment: You need to create a label of that name. Or replace with text.